# How to play Animation after touching the button?

Tags: android, animation, button, android-studio

I am creating a simple app that plays animation after touching the given button.
But the app crashes after touching the button. HELP PLEASE.
I am unable to figure out the problem.

```
    public class thumb extends Activity {
ImageButton show;
final ImageButton show2=show;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_thumb);
    show=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    show.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ImageView countDown = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.a);
            countDown.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation);
            AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =
                    (AnimationDrawable) countDown.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
            {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), pop.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                    }
                }, 3000);
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

};
```

}

Here is the Animation XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


     android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/a" android:duration="1000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/b" android:duration="1000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/c" android:duration="1000"/>

 </animation-list>
```

Here is the Logcat

```
12-24 21:16:53.364    2577-2577/com.example.aksh.funastro E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
12-24 21:16:53.364    2577-2577/com.example.aksh.funastro E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-24 21:16:53.404    2577-2577/com.example.aksh.funastro E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.aksh.funastro.thumb$1.onTouch(thumb.java:47)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7708)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2277)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7893)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5612)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 21:16:53.404    2577-2577/com.example.aksh.funastro D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-24 21:16:53.414    2577-2577/com.example.aksh.funastro W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4162ece0)
12-24 21:16:53.434    2577-2577/com.example.aksh.funastro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aksh.funastro, PID: 2577
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.aksh.funastro.thumb$1.onTouch(thumb.java:47)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7708)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2277)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7893)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5612)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 21:16:53.454      506-760/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.aksh.funastro/.thumb
```

Comment: We need your exception report to help

Comment: I have added logcat  @Android